# Attempting to scrape prices of products from a certain website to use for competitor analysis (non work related)

Tags: python, excel

firstly, I apologise if this question is asked a lot, or seems very simple.  But, I am completely new to python and do not understand much.

There is a website: wiggle.co.uk.  My goal is to scrape the prices (and names!) of products on there for a project I am doing.  I already have a list of given products (mountain bikes) and the corresponding prices.

I have installed python and am ready to start scripting.

I have already inspected the webpage (https://www.wiggle.co.uk/cycle/mountain-bikes) where I want to scrape the prices and have found the blocks of code that contain the names of the bikes and the prices:

```
<a class="bem-product-thumb__name--grid" href="https://www.wiggle.co.uk/vitus-mythique-29-vrs-mountain-bike-2021" data-ga-label="Position 2" data-ga-action="Product Title">Vitus Mythique 29 VRS Mountain Bike (2021)</a>

                    <div class="bem-product-price--grid">
    <span class="bem-product-price__unit--grid">&#163;1,649.99</span>
</div>
```

This can be found on line 3663 if inspecting the above webpage.

I followed a tutorial that scrapes the top 10 films from the top 250 on IMDB.

I altered the code to suit my needs as follows:

```
Import requests
From bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Page = requests.get(https://www.wiggle.co.uk/cycle/mountain-bikes)
Soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, ‘html.parser’)
Links = soup.select(“bem-product-thumb__name—grid”)
First48 = links[:48]
For anchor in first48:
   Print(anchor.text)
```

I assume I am not using the correct 'links' as when trying to run the code.  My question is how I should be inspecting the webpage in order to extract the correct information to be putting in the python code.

I need the :

Vitus Mythique 29 VRS Mountain Bike (2021)

and

1,649.99

Could anyone assist?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.wiggle.co.uk/cycle/mountain-bikes")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
bikes = soup.select(".bem-product-thumb__name--grid")
currency_pattern = r"\$\d+,?\d+.\d+"
for bike in bikes:
    name = bike.text
    price = re.findall(currency_pattern, bike.parent.text)
    print(name, price)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.wiggle.co.uk/cycle/mountain-bikes")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
divs = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'bem-product-list-item--grid js-result-list-item'})
for div in divs:
    name = div.find('a', {'class': 'bem-product-thumb__name--grid'}).text
    price = div.find('span', {'class': 'bem-product-price__unit--grid'}).text
    print('Bike name: ' + str(name))
    print('Price: ' + str(price))
```

Instead of `html.parser` use `lxml`.
After `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` insert `import lxml` and install the package